# Kafka Consumers consumes processed messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are experiencing issue with Kafka consuming old messages after commiting latest offset. Here is logs:

```
2023-11-17_19:26:11.142 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-2 to offset 3812355.
2023-11-17_19:26:11.144 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-0 to offset 3812363.
2023-11-17_19:26:15.988 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 to offset 3812376.
```

here we reseting offsets to 3812***

Then later:

```
2023-11-17_19:28:18.944 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3818583: The request timed out.
2023-11-17_19:28:31.038 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3818973: The request timed out.
2023-11-17_19:28:36.653 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3818973: The request timed out.
2023-11-17_19:28:50.248 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3819564: The request timed out.
2023-11-17_19:28:55.848 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3819564: The request timed out.
2023-11-17_19:29:16.260 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3820398: This is not the correct coordinator.

etc. 


 2023-11-17_19:44:21.139   Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3841718: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
 2023-11-17_19:44:25.169   Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3841718: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
 2023-11-17_19:49:29.998   Kafka commit took longer than `commit-time-warning`: 1260 ms
 2023-11-17_19:51:48.214   Kafka commit took longer than `commit-time-warning`: 3506 ms
 2023-11-17_19:51:48.215   Kafka commit took longer than `commit-time-warning`: 3436 ms
 2023-11-17_20:04:46.858   Kafka commit took longer than `commit-time-warning`: 3159 ms
 2023-11-17_20:10:02.888   Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-2 at offset 3842161: The request timed out.

Revoking previously assigned partitions [<TOPIC_NAME>-0, <TOPIC_NAME>-1, <TOPIC_NAME>-2]
 2023-11-17_21:28:39.273   (Re-)joining group
 2023-11-17_21:28:39.274   (Re-)joining group
 2023-11-17_21:28:42.285   Successfully joined group with generation 5
 2023-11-17_21:28:42.285   Setting newly assigned partitions: <TOPIC_NAME>-0, <TOPIC_NAME>-1, <TOPIC_NAME>-2
 2023-11-17_21:28:42.287   Setting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-2 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=3879118, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=<HOST>-app-01.<COMPANY_NAME>:9093 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=24}}
 2023-11-17_21:28:42.287   Setting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=3879128, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=<HOST>-app-04.<COMPANY_NAME>:9093 (id: 4 rack: null), epoch=31}}
 2023-11-17_21:28:42.287   Setting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=3879139, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=<HOST>-app-02.<COMPANY_NAME>:9093 (id: 2 rack: null), epoch=34}}
```

also there is many logs that something is wrong with coordinator:

```
2023-11-17_19:39:20.226 Offset commit failed on partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 at offset 3832037: This is not the correct coordinator.
  2023-11-17_19:39:20.226 Group coordinator <HOST>-app-05.<COMPANY_NAME>:9093 (id: 2147483642 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
  2023-11-17_19:39:20.257 Kafka commit took longer than `commit-time-warning`: 8129 ms
  2023-11-17_19:39:20.327 Discovered group coordinator <HOST>-app-02.<COMPANY_NAME>:9093 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
  2023-11-17_19:39:20.678 Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id consumer-1-571940b9-43c0-49d1-9560-56e9a8cc5afa is not valid.
```

So the problem is that as you can see from logs we've set offset to 3879*** in **2023-11-17_21:28:42.287**

But hour later we got this:

```
 2023-11-17_22:49:46.159  (Re-)joining group
 2023-11-17_22:49:46.161  (Re-)joining group
 2023-11-17_22:49:49.198  Successfully joined group with generation 1
 
 2023-11-17_22:49:49.199  Setting newly assigned partitions: <TOPIC_NAME>-0, <TOPIC_NAME>-1, <TOPIC_NAME>-2
 2023-11-17_22:49:49.199  Found no committed offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-0
 2023-11-17_22:49:49.199  Found no committed offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1
 2023-11-17_22:49:49.199  Found no committed offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-2

2023-11-17_22:49:49.201 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-0 to offset 3812363.
2023-11-17_22:49:49.202 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-2 to offset 3812355.
2023-11-17_22:50:00.799 Resetting offset for partition <TOPIC_NAME>-1 to offset 3812376.
```

For some reason it resets offset to the 3812*** when we already commited 3879*** an hour ago, because of that our consumers starts to reconsume messages that already been processed.

Maybe some of you guys experienced something like this before? If so are there any suggestions?

If you need any other details, configs, logs etc. feel free to comment! Thanks in advance!